Comando para seleccionar texto actualmente visible en la pantalla?
Me pregunto si existe un comando en VBA (en concreto uso office 2003) para seleccionar, en un documento de Word, el texto que está visible en ese momento en la pantalla.
Supongo que una manera de hacer esto sería usando Getpoint para definir un Range que abarque desde la parte más superior a la más inferior de la pantalla visible.
Pero, para no perder tiempo, antes de ponerme a ello me gustaría saber si existe un comando que realice esto. Y si no, en su caso, otra estrategia más eficiente.
Muchas gracias

Has probado con ActiveWindow.VisibleRange? Y luego con ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Select?

No puedo usar VisibleRange porque veo que Office 2003 solo contempla este comando para Excel, no para Word. Lo se, trabajo con una versión paleolítica de Office... nunca veo el momento de migrar Office365 todo el código que tengo escrito para 2003

En realidad no es cuestión de versiones de Office. VisibleRange no es un comando de Word, tampoco en Office 365, sino solo de Excel. Es decir, que VisibleRange no es una solución pues no existe en Word

Eso parece. Estaba convencido de haberlo usado alguna vez pero buscando entre mis ejemplos de Word no lo he visto... Tal vez usando la API de Windows para controlar las ventanas pueda hacerse algo.
